# Apache reverse proxy, one server, multiple domains

Tags: apache, redirect, debian, reverse-proxy

I am trying to manage 2 domains with one server (running proxmox with several CT), I am using reverse proxy but seems to be wrong.. here's my configuration:

Let's say we have the main server running proxmox where I managed IPTables to redirect port 80 to the port 80 of my first container (CT01) and port 8109 to port 80 of my second container (CT02).

While using the port in my browser, everything is working well, and I am able to reach each container.

I bought 2 domain names, one for my private server (CT01) and another one for a business server (CT02). I associated both of the domain to my server address, and while typing one or another of them I am redirected to CT01 (normal, browser is running the address to the default port).

So now I tried to use reverse proxy in order to redirect to the desired server (DomainA -> CT01, DomainB -> CT02), I created 2 files in `/var/apache2/sites-available/` :

/var/apache2/sites-available/domainA.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/apache2/sites-available/domainB.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainB.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://x.y.z.h:8109/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://x.y.z.h:8109/
    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I runned `a2ensite domainA.com` and `a2ensite domainB.com`. I restarted my apache service.

But nothing have changed: both my `domainA` and `domainB` redirect me to the same container (CT01).

Any idea?

Comment: for questions related to server-administration, please use [sf]

Answer (score 0):

What i may suggest is doing a new CT just to host a proxy (nginx for example) that will route the requests to one or the other site depending of the Host: field value of the HTTP request. This may be a little bit overkill if it's just for two sites, but when you want to have more, it can be very useful. Plus the NGinx can be used to cache, etc.

Let me know if you are interested. I know a tutorial that you may follow, but it's in french : http://blog.ganbaranai.fr/2013/08/il-etait-une-fois-proxmox-derriere-une-ip-unique/

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this alternative is interesting, I outwent my issue by restarting all my conf. I will study your solution deeper and see wether it could be a good choice in my situation.